# How do I get a CSS object to move using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a JavaScript game and I need a CSS object with an animation to move in place of an object I originally made using JavaScript. Basically, what I want to happen is have my "sword" CSS object move with my player object when I have it Unsheathed. I have been looking for a while and they only give me a result as to were it will be when the page is loaded. I need the sword to always be moving with the player. If my code is needed, tell me, and I will provide it. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I am pretty new so go easy on the terrible JavaScript that may be provided.

**PLEASE USE AN EXAMPLE RELATED TO MY CODE!**
if you don't I probably wont understand what is going on....

**Thank You in Advance**

Comment: Can you give an example of your code and CSS?

Comment: The Main section has been updated with my code

Comment: I would recommend that you run your javascript code through a validator: http://beautifytools.com/

Comment: Can you come up with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing the the following element of your example I am only going to address CSS here...

```
....
    <div class="player"></div>
    <div id="swordl"></div>
    <div id="swordr"></div>
....
```

To move `#swordl` and `#swordr` along with `.player` you can take advantage of a feature of the CSS `position` attribute.

When a containing element has CSS `position: relative;` children of that element with the CSS `position: absolute;` are positioned with reference to the top-left corner of the parent.

In the following example `#player` would be the parent, and `#swordl` and `#swordr` would be the children...

```
....
    <div id="player">
        <div id="swordl"></div>
        <div id="swordr"></div>
    </div>
....

/* CSS */
#player {
    position: relative;
}

#swordl, #swordr {
    position: absolute;
}

#swordl {
    left: 4px;
    top: 2px;
}

#swordr {
    left: 12px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

*Note the change of `class` to `id` in 'player'*

Now, whenever you animate the position of `#player` the two `#swords` will maintain their position relative to the top-left corner of their containing parent element: you will not have to animate the position of `#swords` explicitly.

Hope that helps. ;)

---

- [CSS position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: While this is very helpful. The problem is, my player is not a CSS object, it is a JavaScript Object. so how would I link the CSS version to the JavaScript version? also, Everything, such as eyes and the head positions, are linked to the players JavaScript model. So deleting and redoing is not an option in this case. I also have a lot of code linked to it.

Comment: Also. the code does not work properly when used with my code. even after a bit of tinkering.

Comment: @Doodle123 Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  I assumed that the player was rendered to the page as HTML - in which case the CSS `position` rule holds true if if you control its location, orientation, movement with JS.

Comment: So if I were to make a CSS object with the same name as my JavaScript object without putting stuff like x,y,width, and height, it would just link to my JavaScript object?

Comment: @Doodle.  CSS **selectors** and their **rules** define **HTML Element** properties independently of JavaScript.  HTML Elements can be identified with JavaScript and manipulated (change dimensions, colors, positions, remove/swap classes etc). The CSS and the JS can reference the same HTML Element but we use CSS for styling (inline or in a stylesheet) and JavaScript for manipulation and control.  My answer tells you that you can define the 'player' along with the 'swords' with CSS so that you only need to animate the 'player' HTML Element and the 'swords' will move along with it.

Comment: thank you for explaining. My issue now is that the sword(rectangles) don't appear near the player. can adding things like `animation-name` and `transform` effect this outcome? If not, than what do I have to do to make them appear? I have followed your code to a T (except for the 3 dots before and after the HTML example) . From the HTML to the CSS. What would cause this? Am I supposed to change something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `transistion`. I have included a couple examples. One example is just JavaScript, the other is not just JavaScript.

```js
//Get Element By Id of 'movingdiv'
var div = document.getElementById('movingdiv');

//Create the timeout (not required)
setTimeout(function() {

  //Change the style.top to 50%, You can also do this in px
  div.style.top = '50%';
  
  //Change the style.top to 50%, You can also do this in px
  div.style.left = '50%';
  
  //Add the transform so it can be centered in the viewport
  div.style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)';
  
  //Add the timeout below in milliseconds.
}, 1000)
```

```css
#movingdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id='movingdiv'></div>
```

```js
//Create a div
var div = document.createElement('div');

//Give the div some style. IMPORTANT: notice the transition
div.style = 'width: 100px; height: 100px; background: black; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; transition: all 2s;';

//Append the div to the body
document.body.appendChild(div);

//Create a timeout for the div to move
setTimeout(function() {

  //Change the style.top to 50%, You can also do this in px
  div.style.top = '50%';
  
  //Change the style.top to 50%, You can also do this in px
  div.style.left = '50%';
  
  //Add the transform so it can be centered in the viewport
  div.style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)';
  
  //Add the timeout below in milliseconds.
}, 1000)
```